# Python object appears as map (dict) but can't call by attribute or __getitem__?

Tags: python, oop, object, dictionary, attributes

I have an object `myobj` (an instance of `MyObj`) in python which, when called with `print()`, prints

```
{"host": "localhost", "user_indices": [], "password": null, "port": 27017}
```

So `myobj` appears to be a dictionary-style object. But `myobj['host']` raises

```
TypeError: 'AutoProxy[MyObj]' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

And I get an `AttributeError` when trying `myobj.host`.

I've also tried using `myobj.__dict__['host']` and `dict(myobj)['host']` to no avail. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: What Python module are you using here?

Comment: Is one of these methods overridden in `MyObj` class or its superclasses: `__repr__` or `__str__` or `__unicode__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as "null" in python. You should use "None" instead. When you are using null the code should raise a NameError.
Second, try this code, maybe just switching the null to None should fix the problem:

```
>>> temp = {"host": "localhost", "user_indices": [], "password": None, "port": 27017}
>>> temp['host']
'localhost'
>>>
```